# Software to teach my class from distance

Tags: web-apps, chat, streaming, hosted

I have to go overseas for two weeks. Some of my students will also attending some two-week-long workshops but I (also my students) would like to have our class running during these days (4 sessions, 2 weeks × 2 sessions each week).

Is there any software available and suitable?

- I need to talk
- they may ask and may also send some documents, but I can handle the docs using email or apps like WhatsApp or Telegram or whatsoever
- kind of voice streaming (this is what I wonder about)

Comment: Why not Google Hangouts or Skype?

Comment: please give a longer explanation... do the work as a voice chat room!?

Comment: As Jedi said you can start a google hang out,skype, or etc session and have all you students join it.  You will see all of them and they will see you with video and audio.

Comment: but aren't there any software designed for this situation!?

Answer (score 2):

[Teamviewer](https://meeting.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) is the software I've been favoring lately, so I'll add it to what the others said.

Features:

- screen sharing
- audio and video sharig
- file transfer capabilites
- free for personal use
- cross-platform

Comment: what is this software designed for!? I really look for a software designed for this situation, if there exists any!

Comment: At the time of writing this, the following link: https://meeting.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx mentions and then details the "Online Presentation / Meeting". It seems if would fit your usage scenario quote well.

Comment: In other words: yes, it is designed for this exact situation - you share your screen with other people you invited to partake in your presentation, you can interact via video/voice and you can send/receive files.